# Any words or expressions to describe this situation

Tags: word-choice

I am interested in someone at my workplace and want to concentrate on tasks,but unconsciously take a glance at the person again and again. Is there any word to describe the situation? It would not be close to the following words that i came up with such as "concern"or"she has been on my mind".

Much appreciated if you could give me an example and best choice word.

Comment: Are you asking about words for your general state of mind? Or words for occasionally being distracted by your crush? Or more specific words for unconsciously looking at someone/something you're trying not to think about? I ask because I really can't think of any word that captures all 3 facets of your request.

Comment: It seems you are "distracted"

Comment: What I wanted to know appropriate words for the situation is those words such as "distracted" and "be obsessed with". I always wonder how do native speakers say "Kininaru(Japanese)" in English because "Kininaru" has a bunch of meanings as in "Worry","Concern","Distracted","Annoying" and so on. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: "infatuated" would be one

Answer (score 2):

This question is not about English. It's about love. :)

I'm thinking of an expression, not a word, to describe how you feel:

> "Can't take my eyes off you"

There's even a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT4GIljqr-A) you can hum or whistle when you think about that person.

Answer (score 1):

Depends who's describing the "interest":

1. The *verb* **charm** describes a subjective or individually pleasing interest, as from beauty or charisma.
2. *Nouns* and *phrases* like **daydreaming**, **mooning over**, or **making eyes at** describes how a businesslike supervisor might regard such interest.
3. *Verbs* like **bother**, **annoy**, **disturb** or **perturb** might describe the subject's own *reluctant* interest.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are *distracted* by the person in your office? This word can have a positive or negative connotation depending on the context - see my two examples below.

1). Negative use of **distracted:**

I am *distracted* at work because, like a reflex reaction, I often find myself glancing at my colleague to make sure that she is working and not playing games on her mobile phone.

2). Positive use of **distracted:**

I am *distracted* at work because our new member of staff is such a lively and attractive person that I find myself quite unable to stop glancing at her.

**Distracted:** "Unable to think about or pay attention to something: unable to concentrate". (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: It's been discussed in meta, and a link to the definition would make this answer more serviceable.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I can't see this on ELU meta. Please give me some pointers as to how I might locate this discussion on ELU meta. Once I have read the discussion I shall return to my question and edit my answer but wonder how this can be rendered more serviceable over and above the two scenarios I have used in my answer. Any pointers? Thanks.